# add a permenant html element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make so when I create the TD element for the HTML I want it to stay there after the page refreshes. Right now the element just disappears when I refresh the page.
Can someone give me some Tips on how to solve this problem?

```js
if(SkottX == posX && SkottY >= 510){


 alert("Your Finale Score is " + Score); 
 myFunction();
 location.reload();

}

function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "Score:";
    cell2.innerHTML = Score;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
  table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
    td{
    height: 20px;
    width: 25px;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body onLoad="Initialise()">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="600" style="border:10px solid #000070">
  </canvas>
  <button onclick="gameState = states.RUNNING">Start!</button>
  <table id="table" height="900" width="1200" style="display: inline-block">

  </table>
<script src="JSgameStarship3.js">
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to save your data somewhere like a database or the browser localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only modify the in-memory DOM of the current page, then that is all you will modify.

To persist the changes, you need to explicitly store them.

There are two basic approaches to this:

1. Store them somewhere on the client (such as in `localStorage`) and use JavaScript to look for the data you stored with the page loads and to reapply the changes if any are found.
2. Make an HTTP request (e.g. with `XMLHttpRequest`) to the server and use server-side code to store the change. If you take this approach, you'll probably want to generate the page using server-side and and data from a database.